CSS select href text AND with specific anchor text
I want to select the hrefs with accompanying anchor text string.
Here is an example:
<p><strong>xxxxx 520dp:</strong> 
<a class="facebook" href="https://facebook.com/6ZdmW2Cwaq/somecrap1.crap.html">facebook</a> 
– <a href="https://google.com/view/somecrap2.crap">google</a> 
– <a href="https://microsoft.net/file/somecrap3.crap.html">microsoft</a></p>

I want the anchor tags hrefs with crap string but without the facebook anchor text.
So in the case above, the last two would qualify.
How do I write the css selector as ?
 a[href*=crap i] not(a[text*=facebook i])

How do I combine the complement of the facebook anchor text in the above selector?
This is just an example to incorporate my underlying logic - get the anchor tag href with a particular substring without the anchor tag containing a particular text substring.
So the way around this was to effectively pipe the output from one to the other using tilde
  a[href*=crap i]~:not(a[text*=facebook i])

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str, features="html.parser")
output = soup.select('a[href*=crap i]~:not(a[text*=facebook i])')

Got this as output:
[<a href="https://google.com/view/somecrap2.crap">google</a>, <a href="https://microsoft.net/file/somecrap3.crap.html">microsoft</a>]


You can't. The CSS spec has not allowed for selecting elements based on the text contents. You'll need to use JS for this.

textisn't a valid attribute selector and not requires the : to be a pseudo class selector. Also, the ~ is selecting a sibling, you're not piping results anywhere. That selector says: "any sibling of an element with an href attribute that contains google and does not have the text (not a valid attribute) of website. Your a tags aren't siblings of each other, because they are in li elements.

Can you post an example of it working? You can answer your own question. Include a stack snippet. Based on your original question and what you want to do, your code looks like it wouldn't work - since there is no sibling element.

I had to rephrase the whole question. The html in my instance was not the same as the one I had put before. I have also included the code and output.

OK. After looking at BeautifulSoup documentation, this isn't a CSS only question. There is no valid CSS selector for what you want. It looks like BeautifulSoup is parsing the text based on the string argument. That's why your selector now works, because your markup accurately reflects what you actually have, and there is a parser that's essentially filling in what you don't want. Glad you got it sorted.
